# How to add dependencies to pom.xml in IntelliJ 14

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have a few dependencies in *Project Structure/Libraries* in IntelliJ 14. How can I add them to my maven *pom.xml*? There is one single tutorial on IntelliJ's website that does not work for me. I don't want to manage them manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be to install the dependency artifacts (most likely jars) into your local maven repo, like this.

[How to install artifacts to your local maven repo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html)

And then add the dependencies into your pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.something</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Yes, this does require going through each artifact manually, one at a time, but it's a one time setup process.

That is the "proper" way. After that, you can do away with library dependencies in your project structure (they will be picked up correctly via maven).

There is the alternative possibility to "hack" in your project libraries path as a sort of "embedded" maven repo in your project, but that's a little bit hacky and I wouldn't advise that.